# If A has characteristic 3, and 5a = 0, then a = 0.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

> [A. 3, P. 202, *A Book of Abstract Algebr* by Pinter] Let A be a finite integral domain. Prove that if A has characteristic 3, and 5a = 0, then a = 0.

Now, this is how I try to prove it. since characteristic with 3, it must be a group with three elements, i.e. $Z_3$. Since $Z_3$ is a an integral domain, then it has no zero divisors. Thus, we can use cancellation property. I.e., $5a=0$ then either 5=0 or a=0 and since $5 \neq 0$, then it must be that $a=0$. Done.

Is there something wrong or is my proof isn't enough since this is first exercise I did in characteristic of a ring and I don't really fully understand.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: not all finite integral domains with characteristic $3$ have only $3$ elements

Comment: In characteristic $3$, $5$ is nonzero. Now use the fact that $A$ is an integral domain.

Comment: It's not true that $A$ must be $\mathbb{Z}_3$, but I don't know why you try to claim this anyway since the only thing that you use it for is to conclude that $A$ is an integral domain, but that is already given to you in the problem statement.

Comment: @Dylan I should say since it is given that it is integral domain, then we know it has a cancellation property and it follows to show that a=0.

Comment: You don't actually need any of the assumptions apart from being characteristic 3 here (just add $a$ to both sides).

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft you mean we add $a$ to both sides to get a+5a = a <==> a(5+1) = a, then by cancellation property, we have 6 = 0 is true (since 6 mod 3 =0).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint** $ $ the kernel of $\,n\to n\cdot a\,$ is an ideal in $\Bbb Z$ containing $\,3,5\,$ so it contains $\,\gcd (3,5)=1$

More simply: such $n$ are *closed under subtraction*, and contains $3$ and $5$ so contains $\,\gcd(3,5).\,$

More conceptually: the *additive order* of $a$ divides the *coprimes* $3$ and $5$ so it must be $1$.

More generally: see [order ideals](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=user%3A242%20%22order%20ideal%22) and [denominator ideals](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=user%3A242%20%22denominator%20ideal%22).

Comment: Explicitly via Bezout $\,1 = 2(3)-5\,\Rightarrow\,  a = 2(3a)-5a = 0 - 0\ \ \ $